# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-admin

I use Django 1.11.3 and I try to redirect user after "Save" button is pressed on some model in admin. So, in my `admin.py` file I have to following code (part of it):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Info

class InfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_change(self, request, object, form_url=''):
        if(object.type == 1):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/pict/data/add/?info=' + str(object.info))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/pict/article/')
admin.site.register(Info, InfoAdmin)
```

but I get the following error after I press the button:

```
AttributeError at /admin/pict/info/58/change/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

I tried also with `redirect` and `HttpResponse`, but the error persists.

Full **traceback**:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/pict/info/58/change/

Django Version: 1.11.3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['pict.apps.PictConfig',
 'suit',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'massadmin']
Installed Middleware:
['whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "/Users/mick/.virtualenvs/gbs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/mick/.virtualenvs/gbs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Users/mick/.virtualenvs/gbs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/mick/.virtualenvs/gbs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  551.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mick/.virtualenvs/gbs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mick/.virtualenvs/gbs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  58.         add_never_cache_headers(response)
File "/Users/mick/.virtualenvs/gbs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py" in add_never_cache_headers
  274.     patch_response_headers(response, cache_timeout=-1)
File "/Users/mick/.virtualenvs/gbs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py" in patch_response_headers
  265.     if not response.has_header('Expires'):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/pict/info/58/change/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method signature of [`response_change`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_change) is incorrect. Try changing the method to:

```
def response_change(self, request, obj):
    if(obj.type == 1):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/pict/data/add/?info=' + str(obj.info))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/pict/article/')
```

Comment: Thanks! Every time I'm redirected to `/admin/pict/article/`, even when `obj.type` is **1** (based on print). Any idea?

Comment: Check what `repr(obj.type)` and `type(obj.type)` are. Perhaps `obj.type` is the string `'1'`, not the integer `1`.